# Is there a way how to compare array from JSON field against JSON_ARRAY in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, mysql-8.0

MySQL table `contacts`

I have a JSON type column `responses`, which content is

```
{"1": ["Yes", "No", "Maybe"], "2": ["Yes"], "3": ""}
```

I would like to know if it's possible in SELECT statement -> WHERE clause to find out if first JSON element is equal with some given array (it would change).

My idea was something like this:

```
WHERE contacts.responses->>'$."1"' = JSON_ARRAY('Yes','No','Maybe')
```

but this doesn't work (even though when both comparison sides included in SELECT statement, they are displayed equally - `'["Yes", "No", "Maybe"]'`). So, is there any other way how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a plenty of functions you can work in Mysql 8 [The JSON Data Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html)

And you can use JSON_EXTRACT to extract your data from your json in the column. Your data you entered in the question is object and you must use `$."1"` to point it. Be careful for array you must use `$[1]`.

The following is an example of your data and your probably output.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (jdoc JSON);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('{"1": ["Yes", "No", "Maybe"], "2": ["Yes"], "3": ""}');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('{"1": ["YY", "XX", "Maybe"], "2": ["Yes"], "3": ""}');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('{"1": ["Yes", "Maybe"], "2": ["Yes"], "3": ""}');

select jdoc 
from t1 
where JSON_EXTRACT(jdoc,'$."1"') = JSON_ARRAY('Yes','No','Maybe');
```

Comment: try this [Online Demo](https://paiza.io/projects/e/j3Uz6PbRWj_CoVWsTVXFYQ?theme=twilight)

Comment: Can we do a like comparison? I mean kind of `JSON_EXTRACT(jdoc,'$."1"') like JSON_ARRAY('Yes','Maybe');`? Here I want to check if *Yes* and *Maybe* are there in the JSON.

Comment: `select jdoc  from t1 where JSON_CONTAINS(jdoc,'["Yes", "Maybe"]','$."1"') `